# Why do water heaters get up to 12 year tank warranties in consumer stores, but only 10 year in supply warehouses?

Tags: water-heater

I'm looking at gas tank water heaters sold in home improvement stores (Rheem Platinum at HD, AO Smith ProMax series at Lowes) and they offer up to 12 year warranty for their top models.  Meanwhile local plumbers who get water heaters from professional supply warehouses say all options (Ruud  made by Rheem, AO Smith ProLine series, Bradford-White) only come with 10 year warranty tops.
What is the reason for that?
It sounds implausible that supply warehouses would sell cheaper models. Does it mean that consumer store labels "stretch" the warranty a bit?

Please advise.

Comment: My understanding from a plumber years ago is that 6 8 10 12 year warranty water heaters are essentially the same, with a prorated warranty built in as a marketing cost.

Comment: Short of one of the stainless steel options that are few and very expensive, that is also my understanding. Same exact tank, different "extended warranty price" built in.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- the difference between 6yr tanks and 12yr tanks is that the latter have an extra sacrificial anode tossed in (attached to the inlet port of the heater, normally)

Comment: Most likely it's just that in a retail setting, the heater may sit on the shelf for a couple of years, whereas the supply house version would not. The details of the warranty might say 10 years from datre of purchase or 12 years from date of manufacture, the retail store is giving only part of the story.